# Best way to integrate Erlang and python

Tags: python, erlang

What's the best way to integrate Erlang and python?

We need to call python functions in Erlang and call Erlang functions in python. At this moment we are trying to use SOAP as a intermediate layer between these two languages, but we have a lot of "not compatible" troubles. Could you advise the best way to perform integration?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you're trying to integrate and what your "not compatible" troubles are?  If you're using SOAP or XML-RPC as an intermediate layer, what are the problems you're experiencing there?  Details, man!!

Comment: Maybe you want to look at https://launchpad.net/twotp

Comment: "best" is undefined in your question.  Do you mean "cheapest"? Do you mean "Most use of IBM Technology"?  Do you mean "requires the most hardware"?  What do you mean by best?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As already mentioned with [erlport](http://erlport.org) you can use [Erlang port protocol](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/ports.html) and [term_to_binary](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1)/[binary_to_term](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_term-1) functions on Erlang side. On Python side there are low level port driver [Port](http://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlproto.py#L86) which can send and receive messages from Erlang and more high level protocol handler [Protocol](http://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/src/erlport/erlproto.py#L41) which simplified situation when you want to call a Python function from Erlang. Currently there are no any auxiliary interfaces on Erlang side but it's possible there will be some in the future. In the [examples](http://github.com/hdima/erlport/tree/master/examples/) directory you can find some example code for different situations.

And feel free to contact me about any ErlPort related topic.

Comment: Wow, the man himself! Thanks to you (and to your collaborators) for a great library.

Comment: the python links are dead, it looks like they have been moved to `erlport / priv / python3 / erlport /`

Comment: @FooBarUser With the new ErlPort version it's actually much easier now. Please check http://erlport.org/docs/python.html for more details.

Comment: thank you, im a bit concerned about the alpha status but will give it a try for fun.

Comment: @FooBarUser It's in alpha because I still want to add some functions to the API. Currently there are only two bug reports open (the other two are feature requests) which I want to fix soon so I consider it stable enough.

Comment: As far as I understand, erlport is dead. Are there any replacement to it?

Answer (score 11):

In my experience, the best is [erlport](http://erlport.org/).

It allows you to build an Erlang port in Python by satisfying the Erlang port protocol. It handles the data compatibility issue by implementing the Erlang external term format. The linked page shows a clear example of how to use it.