# How can I call erlang from Python?

Tags: python, erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to integrate erlang and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990344/best-way-to-integrate-erlang-and-python)

To use some powerful features of erlang, I should call erlang program from Python, How can I do that? Thank you~

Comment: Can you provide a description of the problem you are trying to solve?  I'm struggling to think of a valid use-case for an Erlang application being managed by a Python app.  What powerful features are you referring too?

Answer (score 8):

In Erlang , you can communicate with the external world using ports which provides a byte oriented interface to the external program.

You can also have a look at [erlport](http://erlport.org) which is a python library implementing the Erlang port protocol.

Comment: I'v found the way to call python from erlang, but I don't know how to call erlang fron python.Even the erlport, looks only supply the way to call python from erlang.

Comment: ok. Another thing what you can try is to run the Erlang Virtual machine as a daemon using the "runerl" command. This will create two named pipes in "/tmp" for reading and writing purpose (erlang.pipe.1.r And erlang.pipe.1.w) . Using python you can write the command(as you use in erlang command line) to the named pipe , the VM will execute it and you can fetch the output from the read named pipe. Hope this is what you need .

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [BERT-RPC](http://bert-rpc.org/). It allows you to perform [remote procedure calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) and casts, request data (including streaming). There you'll find various libraries for some languages including Python.

In your case you might just set up erlang server using [ernie](https://github.com/mojombo/ernie) and communicate with it via [python-bertrpc](http://github.com/mjrusso/python-bertrpc) client. Both projects are documented.

Answer (score 1):

We mostly use JSON over HTTP to do this. In some cases you might want to use a more robust messaging protocol (e.g. AMQP with RabbitMQ), but there's rarely a good reason for Python to directly speak the Erlang distribution protocol. Sometimes we use erlport to serialize things instead of JSON, when performance is a little more important.