# The erlport.erlang module doesn't seem to exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, erlang, elixir

The [ErlPort docs](http://erlport.org/docs/python.html) for making calls to Erlang functions in Python requires importing erlport.erlang and using the call function. It seems that in erlport 0.6 (the version that pip3 install) there is no erlport.erlang module.

I've searched around a bit and am not sure how to go about this, as most of the erlport docs/issues are pretty outdated. The repo and package themselves haven't gotten me anywhere. I am attempting to make calls to erlang functions from a Flask app. Erlport seems to be the best tool for this as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990344/best-way-to-integrate-erlang-and-python) and quite a few others.